# Drawer + Tab + ViewPager and each fragment load data from server

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Some menu in the drawer will open Tab + ViewPager content. Each page (fragment) is list that its data is requested from server.

Every time I click that menu, I want the content will show the tab immediately even the data are still requested instead empty screen. I try to add progress bar in the TabFragment so the content will show a loading when preparing the ViewPager and the pagers' data. But, the content still show an empty screen without loading indicator. I found the problem is because the method to request data from server is called from each pager.

Should I move the method for requesting data to TabFragment?

My TabFragment class looks like:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .....

    content = view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    farmerViewPagerAdapter = new FarmerViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), titles);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    viewPager.setAdapter(farmerViewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.post(()->{
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; ++i){
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(icons[i]);
            }
        });
}
```

And here is fragment for each page (each page requests different data):

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    this.view = view;

    emptyView = view.findViewById(R.id.emptyView);
    emptyText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emptyTextView);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    adapter = new FarmerAdapter(data, getContext());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getContext())
                    .showLastDivider()
                    .marginResId(R.dimen.divider_margin_left, R.dimen.divider_margin_right)
                    .build());

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {

                if (!Util.isNetworkAvailable(getContext())) {
                    if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                } else {
                    currentPage = 1;
                    loadData(); //method to request data from server
                }
            }
    );


    if (user != null) {
        getDataFromLocal();
        addToAdapter();
        loadData();
    }

}
```

(Ed)loadData method :

```
Observable<Response<List<Data>>> dataApi = request.getServerData(currentPage,
            NUMBER_DATA_PER_PAGE, 
            token);
    dataApi.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(responseData -> {
                if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                if (responseData.isSuccessful() && responseData.code() == 200) {

                    currentPage++;

                    adapter.add(responseData.body());
                    if (adapter.getItemCount() < 1) {
                        emptyText.setText("Empty");
                        emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                } else {
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseFarmer.errorBody().string());
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), json.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, error -> {
                if (swipeRefreshLayout != null && swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                if (error != null && error.getLocalizedMessage() != null)
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            });
```

This method is called from pager fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Your AsyncTask has an empty doInBackground() body. That essentially makes it synchronous. Say you have this AsyncTask:

```
private class SetAdapterTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            doPostExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            doPreExecute();
        }
    }
```

and you call this in your code like this:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .....
    new SetAdapterTask().execute();
}
```

but since your AsyncTask doesn't do anything in background, the postExecute fires off right after the preExecute, making the whole thing equivalent to this:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .....
    doPreExecute();
    doPostExecute();
}
```

In other words, you make your ProgressBar visible in preExecute and immediatelly after that you make it disappear in postExecute.

The right way to approach this would be moving the ProgressBar visibility settings to the AsyncTask you use to load your data, which is located somewhere in the loadData() I presume. As for the data loading itself, it's hard to say what is wrong without seeing the actual methods which load the data.

Comment: I add the loadData method. The doInBackgroud() is empty because I can't setAdapter on viewPager and setupWithViewPager on TabLayout. If I didn't use asynctask to setup viewpager, the drawer would freeze a moment before the content change to tab with viewpager.

Comment: Turn out I didn't need asynctask anymore after I change getSupportFragmentManager() to getChildFragmentManager(). The problem is still same, when I click drawer menu, the toolbar title change immediately and the content is still froze and changed after all requests (loadData in each pager) are done. Thing I want to accomplish is when I click drawer menu, the content should changed immediately even all the request are still working.

Comment: In case it's still relevant: I am not very familiar with observables but it seems to me the problem is you're not calling adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() after adapter.add(responseData.body()); Add adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() to refresh your adapter and show newly added data.